# How to configure infinispan cluster with nodes on different machines?

Tags: caching, infinispan, jgroups

I am pretty new to this stuff. My requirement is to use a infinispan 8.1 clustered cache in domain mode. I followed the basic pre configured files. I copied the server project on two different machines on same network. I started them, and they discovered each other. Each machine create 2 nodes, so total of 4 nodes. When I used client program (a hotrod client) to access that, I got the cache from the nodes.

Now when I moved one machine to other network, it stopped working. What could be the workaround??

Also, I have one more doubt. In hotrod client API, I can add clusters and servers etc. Shouldn't it be done from the servet, and client should access it with only one logical name under IP address/Host name??

Also, How can I start the infinispan server as a service??  as I do not want to wrap it inside any web application.

Comment: Probably you have an issue with UDP multicast not getting through between machines. You should either switch the server to using TCP communications for clustering or solve the UDP multicast issues.

Comment: A HR client only needs one IP address from a node to find out the rest of nodes, assuming they've clustered. Also, each server can have an external host/port parameters configured so that you can give it a logical address/port.

Comment: Infinispan Server runs standalone really, you can probably run it as a service but how to do it depends on your env/OS. Infinispan Server is based on top of Wildfly so if you find out how to run that as a service you'll prob find your answer. In absence of that, try finding how to run a Java program as a service.

Comment: @GalderZamarreño : I am still not clear. How can I switch the server to use TCP communication. I start both of them by starting the domain.bat file. can I give an external parameter to this file or should I change the jgroups file (which are inside jar)? If the option is latter, how can I do that?

Comment: My hotrod client does something like this -

`ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();  cb.addCluster("HighQCacheCluster").addClusterNode("jboss1ind1", 11222).addClusterNode("udit.local.com", 11222);

RemoteCacheManager rmc = new RemoteCacheManager(cb.build());`

Comment: @GalderZamarreño : I have seen example in which they're using `GlobalConfiguration` and specifying "jroups-tcp.xml" along with `DefaultCacheManager` , what should be done in above case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101965/discussion-between-udit-mishra-and-galder-zamarreno).

Comment: the steps explained [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/140103) should be applicable to Infinispan Server to switch to TCP based clustering.